# element of fraction of DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

Let us now assume that $A$ is a discrete valuation ring. Any element $\pi \in A$ for which $v(\pi) = 1$ is called a uniformizer. Such a uniformizer necessarily exists, since $v$ maps $A$ surjectively onto $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

If we fix a uniformizer $\pi$, why **every $x ∈ k^\times$** can be written uniquely as
$x = u\pi^n$
where $n = v(x)$ and  **$u = x/\pi^n ∈ A^\times$** ?

I think this is fundamental fact of DVR, but how to prove formally from definition?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just define $u=x/\pi^n$.  Then $v(u)=0$, so $u\in A$.  Also, $v(u^{-1})=0$ so $u^{-1}\in A$ as well, so $u$ is a unit of $A$.